# Autolayout UICollectionviewCell in iOS8

Tags: ios

I have a problem with UICollectionViewCell in iOS 8. It didn't resize like what I expected.

My idea is :

I have an UIViewController class with storyboard
Add an UICollectionView that has size equal with ViewController View
And UICollectionView has cell size equal to its

No matter what I do, the cell didn't resize to its UICollectionView

P/S: I am using size class too

Anyone can show me how to achieve my idea?

Edit: I have resolved my problem. please closed this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to.  See below.  I have the CollectionView selected in the document outline on the left.  Notice the size inspector on the right.  You have to make sure it's size matches that of the underlying ViewController.  In this case 320x568.  I did my best to match the ViewController size manually, but when I looked in the size inspector it was slightly small.  So I adjusted it.  Then you can stretch your collection cell to match in the storyboard.

[image]